# PTIJ: Order, Yahoo and the Torah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Jerusalem Talmud says:

הַקּוֹרֵא לְמַפְרֵעַ לֹא יָצָא. ... אוֹמֵר תַּנָּא נַחְמָן סַבָּא
וְהָיוּ כְּדֶרֶךְ הֲוִייָתָן יְהוּ
. תַּנִּי אַף בְּהַלֵּל וּבִקְרִיאַת הַמְּגִילָּה כֵּן.

> He who reads out-of-order has not fulfilled his obligation...Naḥman the Elder stated: "They shall be" [Deut. 6:6] means "they shall be as Yahoo"... The same holds for Hallel and the reading of the Megillah. [Berakhot Y 2:4, also Megillah Y 2:1]

Does Yahoo really display its search results in any order?  Not in *my* experience.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

[There once was a gentile who came to Hillel](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a.5?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi), it is really a famous story. The gentile asked Hillel if he could learn him the Written Torah, not the Oral Torah, only the Written Torah. Hillel accepted that challenge and explained that the Hebrew Alfabet goes as follow: Alef, Bet, Gimmel etc... it is in a specific order. The next day, however, Hillel taught the gentile that it was: Gimmel, Bet, Alef. The gentile could not believe what Hillel said, how can that be, that the alfabet is the other way around? It should be A,B,C, right?

Yes, Hillel said. Just like the alfabet needs to be in a specific order, so to Yahoo ( יאהו) needs to be in a specific order when displaying search-results.

> תָּנוּ רַבָּנַן: מַעֲשֶׂה בְּגוֹי אֶחָד שֶׁבָּא לִפְנֵי שַׁמַּאי. אָמַר לוֹ: כַּמָּה תּוֹרוֹת יֵשׁ לָכֶם? אָמַר לוֹ: שְׁתַּיִם, תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב וְתוֹרָה שֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה. אָמַר לוֹ: שֶׁבִּכְתָב אֲנִי מַאֲמִינְךָ, וְשֶׁבְּעַל פֶּה — אֵינִי מַאֲמִינְךָ. גַּיְּירֵנִי עַל מְנָת שֶׁתְּלַמְּדֵנִי תּוֹרָה שֶׁבִּכְתָב. גָּעַר בּוֹ וְהוֹצִ**יאוֹ** בִּנְזִיפָה. בָּא לִפְנֵי הִלֵּל, גַּיְירֵיהּ. יוֹמָא קַמָּא אֲמַר לֵיהּ: א״ב ג״ד. לִמְחַר אֲפֵיךְ לֵיהּ. אֲמַר לֵיהּ: וְהָא אֶתְמוֹל לָא אֲמַרְתְּ לִי הָכִי! אֲמַר לֵיהּ: לָאו עֲלַי דִּידִי קָא סָמְכַתְּ? דְּעַל פֶּה נָמֵי סְמוֹךְ עֲלַי.